# xr-hyper include the file name in the reference to an external document

Tags: xr-hyper

I know that I can refer to equation, sections etc from external documents as the example below shows.

But how could I include the name of the external document, in my example

> The main result can be found in \nameref{B-sec:main-result}

Should display (maybe included in the hyperlink which I indicate by using []

> The main result can be found in [docB Main result]

### `docA.tex`

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{xr-hyper} 
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref} 
\externaldocument[B-]{docB}% <- full or relative path 
\externaldocument[C-]{./external/docC}% <- full or relative path 
\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}
\label{sec:introduction}
This is a test for math.
\begin{equation}
  E=mc^2 \label{eq:1}
\end{equation}
This is a second test for math.
\begin{equation}
  r = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2} \label{eq:2}
\end{equation}
In document B Eq.~~(\ref{B-eq:x})

Now test  (\autoref{C-eq:docC:1})

The main result can be found in \nameref{B-sec:main-result}
\end{document}
```

### `docB.tex`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xr-hyper}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\externaldocument[A-]{docA}
\begin{document}
\setcounter{equation}{5}
\section{Main result}
\label{sec:main-result}
  As was shown in Eq.~(\ref{A-eq:1}) is it
  ... or in Eq.~(\ref{A-eq:2}) is ...
  \begin{equation}
    \mathrm{e}^{i\pi}-1=0 \label{eq:x}
  \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

xr-hyper stores the file name in the last argument of \newlabel and you can retrieve it e.g. with \refcount. You can also change the path with the second optional argument of \externaldocument:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{xr-hyper} 
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref} 
\externaldocument[B-]{docB}% <- full or relative path 
\externaldocument[C-]{docB}[some-other-path]% <- full or relative path 
\usepackage{refcount}
\begin{document}
The main result can be found in \nameref{B-sec:main-result}
in file \getrefbykeydefault{B-sec:main-result}{url}{??}
and file \getrefbykeydefault{C-sec:main-result}{url}{??}
\end{document}
```

gives

[image]

The exact output depends on if hyperref is used (both in the main and in the external document) and also on the version of LaTeX and hyperref as we extended recently the LaTeX-\newlabel to align with the hyperref usage. With a new LaTeX hyperref is not strictly needed to get the file name. But aligning xr-hyper with the involved changes wasn't trivial and at least one previous hyperref version had a bug and lost the file name. You get the best results, with hyperref v7.01g and latex 2023-11-01 or newer.

Comment: Thanks very much, that looks very useful for my workflow. Using pdfTeX 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.25 (TeX Live 2023) I obtain the same result as indicated in your pdf. So no update necessary right now for me. What's about backward compatibility. If I collaborate with someone who is using only TL 2019. Would these commands cause problems? Thanks 
Uwe Brauer

Comment: if all documents use hyperref, it should work. If you have a mix, I don't know.